# How can I create text with an engraved effect?

Tags: c++, qt, text-formatting

I have a `QLabel`, and **I want the text** inside of it **to appear engraved**, similar to the text-shadow approach in CSS. Is there a way to do this in Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by overriding the label's paint event in a subclass. Example:

```
#include <QRect>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPainter>

class QEngravedLabel : public QLabel
{
public:

    explicit QEngravedLabel(QWidget *parent=0, Qt::WindowFlags f=0) 
        : QLabel(parent, f){};
    explicit QEngravedLabel(const QString &text, QWidget *parent=0, Qt::WindowFlags f=0) 
        : QLabel(text,parent,f){};

protected:

    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pe) override
    {
        QRect toPaint(pe->rect());
        QPainter painter(this);

        toPaint.translate(0,1);
        painter.setPen(QColor("#CCC")); // light shadow on bottom
        painter.drawText(toPaint, this->alignment() ,this->text());

        toPaint.translate(0,-2);
        painter.setPen(QColor("#333")); // dark shadow on top
        painter.drawText(toPaint, this->alignment() ,this->text());

        toPaint.translate(0,1);
        painter.setPen(QColor("#000000"));  // text
        painter.drawText(toPaint, this->alignment() ,this->text());
    }
};
```

These shadow colors are tailored for a light gray background.

Answer (score 3):

Much more easier than overriding the `paintEvent` is using a [QGraphicsEffect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicseffect.html), precisely [QGraphicsDropShadowEffect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsdropshadoweffect.html).

```
QGraphicsDropShadowEffect* effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect();
effect->setBlurRadius(5);
effect->setXOffset(5);
effect->setYOffset(5);
label->setGraphicsEffect(effect);
```

and the result is something like this:

[image]

If you want to color the shadow you can easily achieve this through [QGraphicsDropShadowEffect::setColor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsdropshadoweffect.html#color-prop) member function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Drop shadow is a much easier method to do something totally different than what I was asking for. The drop shadow effect makes text look like it is floating above the page. An engraved effect makes the text look sunken into the page, so this method does not answer the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, you asked for a `text-shadow` effect, I wasn't familiar what `engraved` looked...